# Decoding Characters as printed in terminal

Tags: python, django

i am having a function that returns a json response in this format when printed in terminal `[{"value": 17, "label": "PENDING_ENROUTE"}, {"value": 1, "label": "REJECTED_PREFIX_MISSING"}]` but if i access the context variable holding the data in template it returns

```
[{u&#39;value&#39;: 17, u&#39;label&#39;: u&#39;PENDING_ENROUTE&#39;}, {u&#39;value&#39;: 1, u&#39;label&#39;: u&#39;REJECTED_PREFIX_MISSING&#39;}]
```

Anyone having an idea on how to resolve it, i have tried alot of ways but i couldn't find any solution. Somebody help.

Comment: @schwobaseggl thank you it worked

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Django's builtin filter [`safe`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/templates/builtins/#safe) will do that for you:

```
{{ var|safe }}
```